# Insert Query in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

```
 $table_name = 'tbl_users';
 $data = array('datetime'=>'NOW()',
                'ipadress' => $ipaddress, 
                'name' => $name,
                'dob' => $dob, 
                'nationality' => $nationality, 
                'address' => $address, 
                'city' => $city, 
                'state' => $state, 
                'pincode' => $pincode,
                'phone' => $phone,
                'email' => $email,
                'mobile' => $mobile,
                'weight' => $weight,
                'height'=> $height,
                'marital' => $marital,
                'degree' => $degree,
                'institute' => $institute,
                'special' => $special,
                'yearofpaas' => $yearofpaas,
                'grade' => $grade,
                'emplyment_history' => $emplyment_history,
                'merits' => $merits,
                'major_achivements' => $major_achivements,
                'interview_attended' => $interview_attended,
                'details' => $details,
                'minctc_position' => $minctc_position,
                'cv_file' => $cv_file,
                'declaration' => $declaration);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data); 
drupal_write_record($table_name, $data);
```

I have this insert query but somehow records are not going in to the table..can anyone please help me...whats the problem in the query ?????

Comment: The problem will probably be the `'datetime'=>'NOW()'` line. Drupal will (correctly) escape that as an argument and the `datetime` field will fail validation. Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35465/how-to-set-a-datetime-field-now-during-insert

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in NOW() as a string, which won't work.  Try instead:

```
$data = array('timestamp' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
```

Answer (score 1):

`drupal_write_record` only works if table schema is present in my_module.install file.

From [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7): drupal_write_record saves (inserts or updates) a record to the database **based upon the schema**.

So, make sure that schema of `tbl_users` table is present.
Also, as mentioned by `Dan U.` use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` instead of **'Now()'**.

Answer (score 0):

The **dblog** can give you a good idea about the problem in your query. The path is **admin/reports/dblog**.